# Memory Allocation and Setting

Tags: c, linux, x86

I'm working through a course, and am being tasked to look through and tweak some C code. I have never written C a day in my life, however I was able to pick up on some of the functions and complete the exercise :)

During the exercise, I was allocating memory space in a buffer and filling that space with arbitrary characters. This was part of a buffer overflow assignment.

I learned two functions:

```
malloc(size_t) - allocates memory with a size_t
memset(ptr, bytes, space) - sets shellcode into the memory
```

I'll use this code block as an example:

```
char *nop = malloc(10);
memset(nop, 0x00, 10);
memset(nop, 0x90, 10);
```

My question is in regards to the code above, where i am reserving space in memory and filling it with nops. Why is it necessary, if at all, that I fill the space with null bytes first before overwriting with my desired characters.

Would the following work the same, or do i need to fill with null bytes first:

```
char *nop = malloc(10);
memset(nop, 0x90, 10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second call to `memset` will completely overwrite what the first `memset` does, so the first one is redundant.

Had you first set all of the bytes to 0, then set a *subset* of them to `0x90`, then it might make sense.  But you're writing to *all* of the same bytes, so no need for the first one.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Originally, the code i was looking at was setting a subset of the bytes to different characters. Which makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call the first `memset` (with `0x00` as the value) first. In fact, I'd expect a decent compiler to completely optimize the first call out if it saw that the very next line was going to fill the exact same chunk of memory with a different byte.